# Please explain this PHP syntax

Tags: php, if-statement, string-comparison

I've looked up the functions in the manual, but I still don't get this. According to the person who wrote the code, if the User enters "y" then the function (not shown here) will execute. However, because of the `!`, it looks to me like the function (not shown here) will execute if the user enters something other than "y".

Please explain (I"m a relative newbie so as much detail as possible would be helpful). Thanks

```
if(!strncasecmp(trim(fgets(STDIN)),'y',1))
```

Comment: Is this in the context of a command line application?

Comment: yes, the script is creating a shell tool

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fgets(STDIN)` - reads a string from standard input(keyboard in your case).

`trim` - removes any spaces surrounding the user input. So if the user enters `' y'` or a `'y '`, it'll be converted to `'y'`

`strncasecmp` - The user might enter either uppercase `Y` or lowercase `y`, this function helps you to compare case insensitive way. Also this function returns `0` if the comparison is successful and then you use the `!` (not operator) which changes the `0` to a `1` so that the `if` test passes.

You could re-write it as:

```
if(strncasecmp(trim(fgets(STDIN)),'y',1) == 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

The function [strncasecmp](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.strncasecmp.php) returns 0 if there is *no difference* between the strings compared, hence the `!` to check if they're equal.

Comment: Yes. Many string comparison functions in a variety of languages/libraries return like this, for sorting purposes -- negative value if the string is "less" than the comparison string, positive value if it's "more" than the comparison string, zero if equal.